# Does a function that returns a variable still run without assignment?

Tags: c

In this specific example, the code would be  `down_interruptible(&semaphore)`.  down_interruptible returns an integer.  Should the function still run appropriately despite  no assignment for the return value, or does the lack of assignment cause the statement to be skipped altogether?

Comment: The C compiler is not allowed to optimize out a function call unless it knows that it produces no side-effects.

Comment: Compile your code to assembler and you will know an answer ;)

Comment: @divanov that was the next step, but even if I got my answer I'd still have liked to know more information about it like if it were bad practice, or that the compiler is/is not allowed to optimize functions which I have learned from this simple question.

Comment: Question to the OP: how often do you use the return value you get from printf() ;-?

Answer (score 1):

You are free to ignore a returned value in C (although it is considered bad practice in some cases, e.g. when an error code is returned), the function call will still be made.

Generally speaking, compiler are not permitted to remove code having **observable side effects**. (So technically speaking, if your function does nothing, the compiler could omit the call)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unless it doesn't make any difference and the compiler finds it handy to optimize the program and cancel the function's call.